# How to query a "Banned user list" with Firestore

Tags: algorithm, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm actually using Firestore, and assume I have more than 100k users.

Here is the Firestore model I actually have :

```
 /users/
  {uid_0}
    /bans/
      uid_1: true
      uid_2: true
  {uid_1}
    /bans/
  {uid_2}
    /bans/
      uid_4 : true
  {uid_3}
    /bans/
  {uid_4}
    /bans/
      uid_0: true
```

Each user can ban N users, and we need to stop any interactions between banned users.

So I need to create a cloud function which return a different result for each user.

[GET] /me/allowed-users (each user will use their own token)

- uid_0 will gets:  [uid_3]
- uid_1: [uid_2, uid_3, uid_4]
- uid_2: [uid_1, uid_3]
- uid_3: [uid_0, uid_1, uid_2, uid_4]
- uid_4: [uid_1, uid_3]

Using Firestore, what is the best way to implement this ?

It can also be done on client side, but it would require each user to sync all the 100k users...

Here is the code I tried on client side :

```js
function getUsersSample() {
  // Array of uid: /users/{uid}/bans/*
  const bannedUsers = getBannedUsers();

  // Considering we don't need rules for the moment
  const usersCollection = Firebase.firestore().collection('users');

  return usersCollection
    .orderBy('last_activity_at', 'desc')
    .limit(50)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      return querySnapshot.docs
        .filter((e) => !bannedUsers.includes(e.id))
        .map((e) => e.id);
    });
}
```

Using this method, I cannot always get 50 users in the result...

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried first to duplicate "/users/uid_0/bans/uid_4" into "/users/uid_4/bans/uid_0" and did the job on client side with a filter. But I don't think this the best way to do.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the code that you've written?

Comment: Here is the code !